# How Do I override button appearance in Codename One?

Tags: java, codenameone

So, I have my theme all set up except for some details. When I run my app using different skins in the simulator the buttons and font colors change to their native settings, which isn't what I want. I assume I would have to override these settings using override in platform, but i'm not sure how.

Answer (score 0):

Open your theme.res file, override the `Button.UIID` in **ALL** settings: `unselected, selected, pressed, disabled`

**EDIT**

This solved it for me at least two times.

Maybe switch from simulator to real device, sometimes the simulator has some weird behaviour

Comment: Ok, so once I override the UIID's I can create my own parameters such as height, width, etc?

Comment: @kamilahcarlisle You can do so if you use the CSS extension for codename one https://www.codenameone.com/blog/rounded-corners-shadows-and-gradients-with-css.html There you can also make them round, colored, shadowed..... But thats a more advanced topic, I would suggest you using the Layoutmanagers to adjust the size according to what they 'think' is best